# Different cat Output for Hard Linked File over SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, cat, character-encoding, iterm2

I have a single initial file created using a `C` program on `OpenSUSE Leap` VirtualBox VM being accessed via `ssh` from `OS X`. The file is created with `mkstemp()` that a hard link is created for using `link()`. When I use `cat` on both of these files, one has an extra newline at the beginning. Why is this?

```
osboxes@linux-9utt:~/dir/> cat temporary
test
test
osboxes@linux-9utt:~/dir/> cat hard_link

test
test
osboxes@linux-9utt:~/dir/> cat -e temporary
test^M$
test^M$
osboxes@linux-9utt:~/dir/> cat -e hard_link
test^M$
test^M$
osboxes@linux-9utt:~/dir/> xxd temporary
0000000: 7465 7374 0d0a 7465 7374 0d0a            test..test..
osboxes@linux-9utt:~/dir/> xxd hard_link
0000000: 7465 7374 0d0a 7465 7374 0d0a            test..test..
```

Note the binary is identical for both files.

Requested output for `ls -li`:

```
osboxes@linux-9utt:~/dir/> ls -li ~/dir/
4325625 -rw------- 2 osboxes users 12 Nov 30 14:31 temporary
4325625 -rw------- 2 osboxes users 12 Nov 30 14:31 hard_link
```

When running from inside the actual VM itself there are no discrepancies.

```
osboxes@linux-9utt:~/dir/> cat temporary
test
test
osboxes@linux-9utt:~/dir/> cat hard_link
test
test
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ls -li temporary hard_link`?  Please edit your question with the output.

Comment: Confirming: (1) the contents of `temporary` didn't change? (2) you didn't sneak an extra `Enter` press at the end of `cat hard_link` before the contents were displayed?

Comment: @AndyDalton added.

Comment: Is `cat` aliased or overridden in any way? `type cat` output would confirm

Comment: @JeffSchaller (1) no, I am inspecting the program while it hangs at a while(1) loop well after it reaches that point. (2) Is that possible? I've performed it many times and the result is the same every time so not likely.

Comment: @JeffSchaller does not look like it, output is `cat is hashed (/usr/bin/cat)`.

Comment: Added to my question that it is an `ssh` session to a VM. I just realized that when I use `cat` from inside the VM the output is expected. Adding to question now.

Comment: I can't reproduce it without cheating (putting a bunch of spaces at the end of the `cat` command). Upvoted & curious!

Comment: @JeffSchaller seems to have been an iTerm 2 issue, something to do with the panes though I doubt I'll be able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an iTerm 2 issue. I had multiple split panes open and once I closed one of the panes the issue was not reproducible anymore in the same window/session.